# Is it possible to discover the kind of vehicle a ride was completed with from the Uber API?

Tags: uber-api

As the title: I'd like to be able to access a specific ride for the signed-in user and know if the vehicle in question was a Prius, Ford Galaxy, E-Class, or whatever. I don't see this in the documentation for the Riders or Rides API - is there any way to get the information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can get the Make, Model, and even license plate from the Uber API by looking at the current trips (You would just have to filter for a status of `completed`):

https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-request_id-get

The response includes details of the vehicle:

```
"vehicle": {
    "make": "Bugatti",
    "model": "Veyron",
    "license_plate": "I<3Uber",
    "picture_url": "https:\/\/d1w2poirtb3as9.cloudfront.net\/car.jpeg"
  }
```

Note that retrieving this data for rides requested by an app *other than* your own (i.e. for any rider) requires `FULL ACCESS` scope for your app:

> Privileged Scope This endpoint requires a privileged scope to be used
>   in production by all Uber riders. You can use this endpoint
>   immediately when authenticated as yourself or any of your 5 registered
>   developers. When you are ready to distribute your application broadly
>   for use by all Uber riders, you may request FULL ACCESS. For more
>   information read about [scopes](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/scopes).